# Is there any way to perform a side-effect within a future chain, without changing the value propagation

Tags: scala, future

I have a future chain the gets a resource, uses it to retrieve some data, then mutates that data and returns the result (still within a future).

I would like to free the resource before returning the future chain, but without having to insert closer boilerplate code (i.e. put the intermediate result into some variable, then return it as the result for the rest of the chain).

I'm looking for something like:

```
.getResource() //returns future
   .flatMap(resource => resource.getUsageResult()) //returns future
    .FUNCTION_I_NEED(resource.free()) 
    //executes for failures and successes, doesn't change propagated exceptions or values
   .flatMap(usageResult => mutate(usageResult)) //returns future
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `andThen`-operator:

```
something.getResource()
.flatMap(resource => resource.getUsageResult() andThen { case _ => resource.free() })
.flatMap(usageResult => mutate(usageResult))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
getResource()
  .flatMap(resource => {
    resource.getUsageResult()
      .map(result => {
        // .map makes sure the usage result is done
        // do your side effect here
        yourSideEffectOn(resource)
        // return the result again so you can do something with it
        result
      })
  })
  .flatMap(usageResult => mutate(usageResult))
```

You should be able to simplify this by using a for-comprehension:

```
for {
  resource <- getResource()
  usageResult <- getUsageResult(resource)
} yield {
  yourSideEffectOn(resource) // will not wait if it returns a future
  mutate(usageResult)
}
```

If I remember correctly, this should work as well:

```
for {
  resource <- getResource()
  usageResult <- getUsageResult(resource)
  _ = yourSideEffectOn(resource) // will not wait if it returns a future
} yield mutate(usageResult)
```

If you want to wait for the side effect to finish as well (and break, if it fails), you can flatMap the side effect as well:

```
for {
  resource <- getResource()
  usageResult <- getUsageResult(resource)
  _ <- yourSideEffectOn(resource) // will wait for side effect to finish
} yield mutate(usageResult)
```